# Is there a better way to implement custom fieldsets in django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-admin

We are adding customized feildsets in admin form to display and save video credits.

here is where we are adding feildsets.

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    fieldsets = super(CreditsAdminMixin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj=None)
    for category in CreditCategory.objects.all().order_by('name'):
        fields = []
        for field in category.fields.all().order_by('name'):
            field_name = "credit_%s_%s" % (slugify(category.name), slugify(field.name))
            fields.append(field_name)
            self.exclude += (field_name, )
        fieldsets.append((category.name, {'fields': fields}))

    return fieldsets
```

> CreditCategory

is  the category for each credit.

> feilds

are the names of every feild in it to which user enters a value.

example: [image]

here is the code to render the form above way:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CreditsFormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper_credits = FormHelper()
    self.helper_credits.form_tag = False
    fieldsets = []
    for category in CreditCategory.objects.all():
        fields = []
        for field in category.fields.all():
            field_name = "credit_%s_%s" % (slugify(category.name), slugify(field.name))
            self.credits_keys.append({"key":field_name,"value":field})
            initial = None
            if self.instance.pk:
                try:
                    initial = str(self.instance.credits.get(field=field))
                except Credit.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
                except Credit.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                    pass
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(label=field.name, initial=initial,max_length=255,
                                                                             required=False, validators=[validate_credit_field])
            fields.append(Field(field_name))
        fieldsets.append(CollapsibleFieldset(category.name, ColumnFields(*fields)))
    self.helper_credits.layout = Layout(*fieldsets)
```

And here where we save credits:

```
def save_credits(self):
    instance = self.instance

        for field in CreditField.objects.all():
            name = self.cleaned_data["credit_%s_%s" % (slugify(field.category.name), slugify(field.name))]
            if name:
                credit = instance.credits.filter(field=field).first()
                if credit:
                    credit.name = name
                    credit.save()
                else:
                    credit = instance.credits.create(field=field, name=name)

            else:
                instance.credits.filter(field=field).delete()
```

This works fine, up until few weeks ago. But, Now, as the credit feilds for each getting increased gradually, we are getting 502 timeout errors while saving the form. Is there a better way to implement feildsets. OR something is not right while saving them. Can I optimize something there?

Comment: Can you post the `CreditCategory` model? Is `fields` another database model? You could probably optimise it using `select_related` or `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Thanks,this seems useful. I will try this.